# Syntax issue while inserting data using transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Below is sample code:

```
create table abc (id int auto_increment primary key, cost numeric not null);

start transaction;
        insert into abc (cost) values (199.99);
commit;
```

Error message:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=11) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into abc (cost) values (199.99);

Please advice, Thanks

Comment: Create table is missing a terminator..

Comment: okay, even without the terminator the table gets created. Added the terminator now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error in mariadb locally or mysql here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7eae99f75c73143b165ec0d38b864770

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: BTW you have not specified number of decimals for cost so expect rounding to integer..

Comment: Strange I tried the same in the mysql shell and it works fine. When I run the command in the DBEaver it fails. 10.4.24, it came along with XAMPP package.

Comment: You should add this new information to the question. Perhaps the incorrect cost definition is being caught but not accurately reflected in the error message.